# UML modelling program

Tags: eclipse, uml

I was just wondering what did [the UML diagram from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992860/is-this-a-circular-dependency) made from?
the interface looks good and I think it's eclipse compatible.
maybe you know what program could produce this kind of UML diagram?

(sorry cant post pic because of low reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definitely looks like IBM Rational's Modeling Software. The Rational Software Architect family to be specific: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/products/rsa/

See the screenshots here for comparison: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soa-bddhealth/

I'm using it on a daily basis, and it isn't bad. The newest version is Eclipse 3.6-based and leverages the open-source frameworks like EMF, GMF, JET, etc. IBM add a lot of proprietary things, like Java, C++, etc. to and from transformations.

It's very expensive, but their support is very good (if your willing to pay for premium).

If your looking for something open and free, check out the Papyrus MDT project.

Comment: really true. it's not free huh? too bad.. :(
thanks anyway :)